# jQuery add and remove classes and css if it has another class in nested list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a block of HTML code as below.

```
<ul>       
  <li class="level_1 has_sub no_active">
    <a href="">Window Rolling</a>
    <ul class="level_2 has_sub no_active">
      <li class="level_2 no_sub no_active"><a href="">T52</a></li>
      <li class="level_2 no_sub no_active"><a href="">T30</a></li>
      <li class="level_2 no_sub no_active"><a href="">T57</a></li>
      <li class="level_2 no_sub no_active"><a href="">T39</a></li>
      <li class="level_2 no_sub no_active"><a href="">TE26</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="level_1 has_sub no_active">
    <a href="">Insulated And Extruded</a>
    <ul class="level_2 has_sub no_active">
      <li class="level_2 no_sub no_active"><a href="">TE77</a></li>
      <li class="level_2 no_sub no_active"><a href="">TE78</a></li>
      <li class="level_2 no_sub no_active"><a href="">T77</a></li>
      <li class="level_2 no_sub no_active"><a href="">TS77</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="level_1 no_sub no_active"><a href="">Grille Type Rolling</a></li>
  <li class="level_1 no_sub no_active"><a href="">PVC High Speed Doors</a></li>
  <li class="level_1 no_sub no_active"><a href="">Swinging doors</a></li>
</ul>
```

Using this code, I have to check `ul ul li` has a class named `active2`. If that class exist then I want to add classes to its parent elements as below:

```
ul > li.active1 
ul ul.active1 and display: block;
```

Eg:

```
  <li class="level_1 has_sub active1">
    <a href="">Insulated And Extruded</a>
    <ul class="level_2 has_sub active1" style="display: block;">
      <li class="level_2 no_sub active2"><a href="">TE77</a></li>
      <li class="level_2 no_sub no_active"><a href="">TE78</a></li>
      <li class="level_2 no_sub no_active"><a href="">T77</a></li>
      <li class="level_2 no_sub no_active"><a href="">TS77</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

I tried it using `jquery` as below. But that classes and css adding to all `li`s and `ul`s.

```
if ($('ul li ul li').hasClass('active2')) {
  $('ul li')
    .removeClass('no_active')
    .addClass("active1"); 

  $('ul li ul')
    .removeClass('no_active')
    .addClass("active1")
    .css("display","block");   
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: no sure if is gonna work but try this: `if($('.active2').length)` or `if($('.active2')[0].length)` if first say that has not length function

Comment: how are you adding these classes?you can have no_active and active2 at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var removeClass = 'no_active',
    addClass = 'active1';
$('ul ul li')
    .filter(function () {
        return $(this).hasClass('level_2');
    })
    .parent()
    .removeClass(removeClass)
    .addClass(addClass)
    .parent()
    .removeClass(removeClass)
    .addClass(addClass);
```

Comment: Thank you Rechard. Its only added to parent `li`. can you tell me how to add same class and css for parent `ul` also?

Comment: I have updated the answer, try that. It's not very nice though, your code could definitely be optimised

Comment: Thank you, Its working now. Can you explain why its not nice and how to optimized?

Comment: If you have the CSS classes on the `ul`, you don't need to set them on the `li` also, generally. In your CSS you can use `ul.level_2 li`. So basically, remove all of the classes from the `li` and keep them on the `ul` only

Comment: Wait, never mind actually. Just `level_2` could be removed. I didn't look at your HTML very well :-)

Comment: I understand.. Thank you for your explanation.